# React typescript type error with react-spring

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-spring

I'm getting errors while trying to assign styles to a circle.
I'm using [react-spring](https://react-spring.io/)

[My code](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-cache-fpslv?file=/src/DarkModeButton.tsx)

***Errors >***
[image: Photo with errors that I'm getting2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx and cy properties should be supported as CSS property, but it seems they missing in typescript definition. Maybe lack of browser support? You can change them from css to element property, this way you can get rid of the error message.

```
 <a.circle cx={maskedCircleProps.cx} cy={maskedCircleProps.cy} r="9" fill="black" />
```